# Azure Functions app settings prefix gets added

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-functions

I've deployed an Azure Functions container to my AKS cluster. For some reason the function doesn't get loaded because of this error:

```
Storage account connection string 'AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsStorage' does not exist
```

Now I do have an app setting in my local.settings.json called AzureWebJobsStorage, so I don't really know why I'm getting this error. In my function.json I'm only referring to AzureWebJobsStorage. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting shows a connection string (`AzureWebJobsAzureWebJobsStorage`) that does not match what is in your settings (`AzureWebJobsStorage`). It sounds like there is a template copying error somewhere, as the setting should just be "AzureWebJobsStorage". Have you verified that the key is correct in `local.settings.json`?

Comment: I double checked my local.settings.json and the setting "AzureWebJobsStorage" is present. It's adding the prefix for some reason.